# How to suppress block ends in algorithmicx?

Tags: algorithmicx

Is there a way to make `algorithmicx` not display the ends of blocks? I've tried redefining the block's end as empty, but it still typesets an empty line instead of ignoring it completely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algrenewtext{EndIf}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \If{1}
    \State do this
  \Else
    \State do that
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering of the above code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the text printed (in which case, the line is still created, but no text is printed), use package option `noend` to hide the ends of blocks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \If{1}
    \State do this
  \Else
    \State do that
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aye! Thank you, I somehow missed that option in the manual.